# React invalid hook call error and storybook 6

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, storybook

All of my hooks cause the Invalid hook call error, this occurred after installing storybook using `npx sb init`

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { useSectionsQuery } from "../../graphql/generated";
          
export const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const { data } = useSectionsQuery();
            
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200">
                  
    
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#4267B2" }} className="grid grid-rows-1">
        <div className="flex justify-center">
          {data?.sectionMany.map((section: any) => {
            return <Card {...section} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The solution for me:

1. I've removed all *storybook* dependencies from my package.json;
2. I've deleted the yarn.lock file and node_modules folder;
3. I've locked react and react-dom versions on my package.json to
   16.13.1;
4. I've added the following resolutions to my package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
```

5. I've removed react dependencies from workspaces.nohoist on my
   package.json;
6. I've installed Storybook from zero using npx sb init.

Quote from the dev's

> @eric-burel we're revamping a bunch of this stuff in 6.1, like #11628 and also removing the webpack DLLs which also cause lots of dependency sensitivity

Read more [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11904)

Answer (score 1):

For those of you coming here with a NextJS v10 and Storybook v6:
Storybook doesn't support react v17, you can check the mismatched versions by running:
`npm ls react-dom` and `npm ls react`.

Storybook released a beta recently that fixes this, you can install this by:
`npx sb upgrade --prerelease`

More info and conversation here: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12408